# How to programatically add product images in django oscar?

Tags: python, django, image, django-oscar

I am currently programatically importing products into my product catalog, however, I am having difficulty uploading images for each product. Here's what my code looks like:

```py
# frobshop/custom_utils/product_importer.py

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import Product
...

for product in my_product_import_list:
    ...
    product_entry = Product()
    product_entry.title = my_product_title
    product_entry.product_class = my_product_class
    product_entry.category = my_category
    product_entry.primary_image = "product_images/my_product_filename.jpg"
    product_entry.save()
```

The details such as product title and product class are successfully saved when I check using the development server, however, I am unsure how to set an image for each product.

The entire `product_images` folder was initially located outside of my `media` directory, but since I wasn't getting any results, I copy pasted the entire folder of my images into the `media` directory but still with no results.  I am assuming that quite a number of steps are being skipped, and maybe there's a convention on how to arrange images in the media directory.  However, I am not sure where to find these steps and conventions.

Here's the portion of my `settings.py` file that deals with my installed apps, the media directory, and static files:

```py
# frobshop/frobshop/settings.py

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',

    'django.contrib.sites',

    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks',
] + get_core_apps(['custom_apps.shipping', 'custom_apps.payment', 'custom_apps.checkout'])

...


STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

For further clarity, here's my `urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from oscar.app import application
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', application.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do it like this using [**`File`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/file/) class:

```
from django.core.files import File

for product in my_product_import_list:
    ...
    product_entry = Product()
    product_entry.title = my_product_title
    product_entry.product_class = my_product_class
    product_entry.category = my_category
    image = File(open("product_images/my_product_filename.jpg", 'rb'))
    product_entry.primary_image = image
    product_entry.save()
```

### Update

probably you should use [**`OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL`**](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/ref/settings.html#oscar-missing-image-url) in settings:

```
OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL = "product_images/my_product_filename.jpg"  # relative path from media root
```

Alternatively, you can use `ProductImage`, like this:

```
    from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import ProductImage

    product_entry = Product()
    product_entry.title = my_product_title
    product_entry.product_class = my_product_class
    product_entry.category = my_category
    product_entry.save()
    product_image = ProductImage()
    image = File(open("product_images/my_product_filename.jpg", 'rb'))
    product_image.original = image
    product_image.caption = "Some Caption"
    product_image.product = product_entry
    product_image.save()
```

As `ProductImage` has a ForignKey relation to `Product` Model, and [**`primary_image`**](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/0f2c6bf2c822a09ef3760d09e1b5e765b3f28234/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py#L587) is a method in `Product` model, which takes image from ProductImage model, and returns the first one(`ProductImage` objects ordered by `display_order` field in that field)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried this, but the product images still do not show in the django-oscar admin dashboard. I'm still getting the "Image Not Available" placeholder.

Comment: It probably is.  I am using a relative path, and I have copy pasted the image folder onto the 1) project root 2) beside the import script 3) under the media folder 4) under the media/images folder. By the way, I am using an unmodified version of the django-oscar Product class

Comment: I tested the code using relative path from project root.

Comment: @BB I have also added code snippet on how to use Product Image

Comment: Thanks! `ProductImage` worked like a charm. The images are now showing up in the dashboard and in the site. Setting the `OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL` in settings.py also allowed me to set a custom placeholder image for missing images.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how helpful this will be to anyone, but I was getting a `SuspiciousFileOperation` Exception when using @ruddra's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56659516/6158303), even though I was using a tempfile within the media root...

```
File "/Users/user/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 19, in validate_file_name
    "Detected path traversal attempt in '%s'" % name
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: Detected path traversal attempt in '/Users/user/Documents/project/media/images/tmp6xem6hvs'
```

Fixed by first saving the image (got the idea from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57711016/6158303)), then saving the product image:

```py
import tempfile
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
...
lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='media')
f = open('<full_path_to_project>/media/images/my_product_filename.jpg', 'rb')
lf.write(f.read())
image = ImageFile(lf)
product_image = ProductImage()
product_image.caption = "some caption"
product_image.product = product_entry
product_image.original = image
product_image.original.save('my_product_filename.jpg', image) # <-----
product_image.save()
...
```